# CKEditor combining plugin imageUpload and File Manager

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to combine both image uploading plugins, **imageUpload** and **File Manager**. imageUpload handles the copy/paste/drag/drop, and File Manager handles traditional file upload flow via OS file chooser.

My issue is that imageUpload uses a json api and File Manager a jsonP style api.

imageUpload:

```
{"uploaded":"1","url":"http://localhost:8080/hostMyImage?file.jpg"}
```

File Manager:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction("0", "\/userfiles\/images\/file.jpg", "");
</script>
```

My question, how do I configure or extend the File Manager to match imageUpload's json api?